# Kubernetes: How to take a thread dump of an app

Tags: java, kubernetes, thread-dump

I am using openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9 docker image to run my java app in Kubernetes. I wanted to have thread dump functionality for this running app. The java image doesn't seem to have that jstack or jmeter tool within it.

Any idea how can I achieve thread dump?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `java` process is PID 1 in the container, you can [send it a SIGQUIT](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178) and it will emit a thread dump to stdout(?)

```sh
kubectl exec $POD_NAME -- kill -QUIT 1
```

*Apologies for the redhat link, I couldn't immediately find the authoritative source for that on oracle.com*